# How parse Yaml?

Tags: c#, sharpyaml

How parse Yaml to yaml-node tree?

I found [sharpyaml](https://github.com/xoofx/SharpYaml) library but I doesn't found simple samples for yaml loading/parsing/etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var serializer = new SharpYaml.Serialization.Serializer();

        var yamlTree = (Dictionary<object, object>)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(text));
```